# how do i get a rails WHERE query to be more specific? "Like" works, = doesn't

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am very new to Rails and am trying to create a search field to query my database. When I use the WHERE method and use "like", it works, but it's far too broad. If a person's last name is Smith, and I search for "i", it will return Smith as that string contains an "i". How can I make it more specific? I've searched around, read the docs and thought the following should work, but it doesn't return records.

this works

```
def self.search(query)
    where("last_name like ? OR email like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end
```

this does not

```
def self.search(query)
    where("last_name = ? OR email = ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to look more into SQL, as this is very specifically an SQL question. The % operator in SQL returns a fuzzy match. You want a strict match. So

```
def self.search(query)
  where("last_name = ? OR email = ?", query, query)
end
```

or more succinctly:

```
scope :search, ->(query) { where('last_name = :query OR email = :query', query: query) }
```